# Private variable accessed by private method in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function Cons(name) {
var pvar1="hi "+name;
sayhi = function() {
   alert(pvar1);
}
attEvents(){
$('#'+name).bind("click",sayhi);
}
}
var a = new Cons('name1');
var b = new Cons('name2');
var c = new Cons('name3');
```

Let us assume that name1, name2, name3 are all divs. Now, whatever div I click, I am always getting "hi name3". The private variable is having the last stored value in it irrespective of the div clicked. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Probably because `sayhi` is global and `.bind("click",sayhi);` is called some time after the three objects have been created. But to know for sure you would have to correct/clarify this statement: `attEvents(){ $('#'+name).bind("click",sayhi);}`  What is it doing?

Comment: My mistake, attEvents will just attach the events to the div. It will be called at the end of Cons(). And yes sayhi was in global scope. Thanks for the help. Did not know that var should be used even when functions are defined. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sayhi = function() {
   alert(pvar1);
}
```

If you define it without `var` keyword then it is defined as a global. Thus `sayhi` refers to the function defined as a last one. Use

```
var sayhi = function() {
   alert(pvar1);
}
```

or

```
var pvar1 = "hi "+name,
    sayhi = function() {
        alert(pvar1);
    };
```

Note the comma. Or true jQuery style

```
$('#'+name).bind("click", function() {
    alert(pvar1);
});
```